# move parent (empty) without children

Tags: parent

i want to move my parent object (=empty) but without moving the children.  Is that possible ?
I saw the answer from 20/02/18 11.56u IPv6.  But it doesn't work.  I'm on Blender 2.8
Mayby i do something wrong.

Comment: What is "*the answer from 20/02/18 11.56u IPv6*" ?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/101357/83443    i hope i did this right ;-)

Comment: Are you trying to say you have problems installing this add-on?

Answer (score 12):

You can enable "Affect Only: Parents" in the Tool>Options sidebar to affect parents only.
[image]

This feature has been added in [2.81 release](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.81/Transform).