# Moving a parent object is not influencing child objects at all

Tags: constraints, parent

I have a large architecture project that I've been working on since before 2.79. At some point post-upgrade (to 2.8), parent objects (created with ctrl + p) stopped influencing their children. I can parent one cube to another but when I move the parent cube, the child does not move at all. The "child of" constraint works fine.

[image]

This problem only shows up in this blend project. If I create a new blend file, parenting works as expected. I found the blend file I was working on before I upgraded to 2.8, and when I bring it into Blender 2.9, parenting works fine. And when I delete all objects in my project except for 2 cubes, and parent one to the other, the child still does not move, which means other objects aren't causing the problem. This seems to indicate that a setting was changed that broke parenting influence but I haven't been able to find what could be causing it. The problem occurs in both MacOS and Windows 10.

I'm attaching a duplicate blend file with all original project objects removed.

[image]

Comment: thanks for you blend file - > this helps a lot !!!

Comment: Related Duality https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157973/move-parent-empty-without-children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uncheck "parents" here

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That did it. You saved me a painful restore from a previous version. Really wondering how I even managed to turn this on in the first place...

Comment: you are welcome!. i am pretty sure you pressed some "shortcut". I did this as beginner very (too) often and it messed up everything because nearly every key combination does something in blender (and often something different if you do this in different panels). So if you are not sure - don't use shortcuts :) i lost hours of searching because i did this in my first weeks... ;)